# Should I provide an image for not found image?

Tags: website-design, image

As said in title.

Should I intercept a broken link to an image, and provide to user a default image (with a big “not found” maybe, but always a valid image)?

Otherwise is it better to leave the native broken image symbol of used browser?

The context is a simple blog, or portal. The not found image it's a clear error that the admin must resolve. It is not a rule but an exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's an exception and therefore very rare, I'd suggest not to intercept the 404.

Because you'll run into additional problems: you can return a different image, but the *caption* and *alt* text would stay the same. That's confusing for the user and not of any help. Furthermore the user's likely to be accustomed to the default browser image but isn't familiar with your *not found* image.

You just have to be careful that a not found image doesn't break your layout (paragraphs and text flow). So be sure **not** to rely on the image's sizes but to fix the size via CSS and/or html attributes.